# App crashes when trying to login with facebook (IOS)

Tags: facebook-login, swift3, firebase-authentication

**Description/Problem**

I'm using Firebase as my database and Facebook login as my login method. I have followed the documentation on [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login) and on [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios), but I ran into a problem. When I try to login I get the following error message:

"Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" on the line `let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)`

What I am doing wrong? The error occurs right after I have clicked on the Facebook login button.

**Code**

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
        self.loginButton.center = self.view.center
        self.loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        self.loginButton.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)

        //Create label with text and position
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 100, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 100, width: 200, height: 100))
        label.text = "Drag me!"
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        //Gesture recognition
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasDragged(gesture:)))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

        // Gesture transition
    func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view) //self.view
        let label = gesture.view!

        label.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2 + translation.x, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2 + translation.y)

        let xFromCenter = label.center.x - self.view.bounds.width / 2
        let scale = min(100 / abs(xFromCenter), 1)
        var rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: xFromCenter / 200)
        var stretchAndRotation = rotation.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)

        label.transform = stretchAndRotation


        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

            if label.center.x < 100 {

                print("Not chosen")

            } else if label.center.x > self.view.bounds.width - 100 {

                print("Chosen")

            }

            rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
            stretchAndRotation = rotation.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 1)
            label.transform = stretchAndRotation
            label.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2)

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // 
    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        print("User Logged In")

        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            print("User Logged Into Firebase App")
        }

    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User Did Logout")
    }

}
```

Comment: i can't seem to reproduce the error even after i update my code to swift 3. When i updated to swift 3, i made sure i updated the frameworks as well!
How about you paste a copy of your stack trace and then we may get a clearer picture

Comment: Also there are times when a button/label outlet is missing it throws this error.

Comment: @nathvarun Thank you for the feedback. Is your code identical to the one I have posted here? Also, how do you make sure that frameworks are updated? Can you give an example?

Comment: Im not sure but you may have followed my unsureprogrammer tutorials on youtube.
You can check the version of your dependencies from your Podfile.lock
By running a pod update command you can update to the latest versions.